# MySQL: Combine union and top 3 count of leads

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm trying to obtain each campaign type and the three lead names that have the most (top 3) attendances for each campaign type. It should looks something like this:

```
+-------+-----------+
| Code  |  LeadName |     
+-------+-----------+
| WP    | LEAD A    |    
| WP    | LEAD B    |   
| WP    | LEAD C    |   
| CF    | LEAD B    |    
| CF    | LEAD C    |   
| CF    | LEAD A    |  
| TL    | LEAD B    |    
| TL    | LEAD A    |   
| TL    | LEAD C    |  


Campaign Table: CampaignID, CampaignName, CampaignStartDate, Code
Campaign Members Table:CampaignID, LeadID, CampaignMemberStatus, CampaignMemberSignUpDate
Leads Table: LeadID, LeadName, AccountID
```

CampaignID links Campaign --> Members, LeadID links Members --> Leads
I'm struggling on how to union and provide top 3 LeadNames.

Comment: How are these tables related? If at all?

Comment: what's the relation between those two tables? post some sample data for both tables as well

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post.

Comment: how do you get attendances?

Comment: probably just two `LEFT JOIN` based on your table sequence, and `GROUP BY Campaign.Code and Leads.LeadName`

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3 ABC.Code,ABC.LeadName 
FROM 
(
SELECT A.Code,C.LeadName,COUNT(*) as total 
FROM Campaign as A
LEFT JOIN [Campaign Members] as B
ON B.CampaignID = A.CampaignID
LEFT JOIN Leads as C
ON C.LeadID = B.LeadID
GROUP BY A.Code, C.LeadName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
) as ABC
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.